# custom post type archive page/template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I have looking for this issue for 2 days and now decide to put my question here so that i can have proper solution or guidance. I have gone through similar questions on `stackoverflow` but some have solution that did not work for me.. and some yet have not proper answer.

Please go through my code and tell me if there is any mistake I am doing..

I have custom post type of `infographics` and have added a `taxonomy` `infograph_category` to it. code is below.

```
// For Infograph Custom Post Type
function mtc_custom_post_type_infographs() {
/**
 * Post Type: Infographs.
 */
$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Infographs", "" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Infograph", "" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Infographs", "" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "All the infographic content will be posted with this type of post",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => false,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "infographics", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt" ),
    "taxonomies" => array( "infograph_category" ),
);

register_post_type( "infographics", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'mtc_custom_post_type_infographs' );

function mtc_infograph_categories() {
/**
 * Taxonomy: infograph categories.
 */
$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "infograph categories", "" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "infograph_category", "" ),
    "all_items" => __( "All Infograph Categories", "" ),
    "edit_item" => __( "Edit infograph category", "" ),
    "view_item" => __( "View infograph category", "" ),
    "update_item" => __( "Update infograph category", "" ),
    "add_new_item" => __( "Add infograph category", "" ),
    "new_item_name" => __( "New infograph category", "" ),
    "parent_item" => __( "Parent infograph category", "" ),
    "parent_item_colon" => __( "Parent infograph category", "" ),
    "search_items" => __( "Search infograph categories", "" ),
    "popular_items" => __( "Popular infograph categories", "" ),
    "add_or_remove_items" => __( "Add or remove infograph categories", "" ),
    "not_found" => __( "No infograph category found", "" ),
    "no_terms" => __( "No infograph categories", "" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "infograph categories", "" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "label" => "infograph categories",
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'infograph_category', 'with_front' => true, ),
    "show_admin_column" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "infograph_category",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
);
register_taxonomy( "infograph_category", array( "infographics" ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'mtc_infograph_categories' );
```

Note: This code is actually generated by CPT plugin

I have created templates for single and category pages like, for single its `single-infographics.php` and for category its `taxonomy-infograph_category.php` and both templates are working fine. But now I want to create a template in which all the post from custom post type `infographs` should shown in there. 
I tried creating some templates like 
`archive-infographs.php`
`taxonomy-infographs.php`
`taxonomy-infograph_categories.php`
`archive-infograph_categories.php`

but nothing works.

I just need a guidance where I am wrong are what is wrong with this code.
Please do not discourage this post, as I have already mentioned that I have gone through lots of questions and googled alot.. but after I failed to get any proper solution for my problem I am posting this is here! Hope you understand and I will get proper guidance/solution!

Thanks

Comment: try to set `has_archive" => true` while creating CPT

Comment: changed to true... what should I name my template now?

Comment: archive-infographics.php

Comment: and what will be the url for that template?

Comment: yourdomain.com/infographics

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: you need to update permalink when you made all of the above changes

Comment: yes :) thank you sooo much ! got that... thanks to @ShravanSharma

Comment: and @Owi , thanks to you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go through CPT UI plugins settings in `Registered Types/Taxes` you can find exactly what you need, like template hierarchy.

just change the value of `has_archive` from `False` to `True` and see template hierarchy in CPT UI plugins. you will find all the required templates for each type.

Comment: thanks buddy! I just got the answer from comments and your answer is appreciated too! :)